# Поступление данных из цикла в массив

Tags: массивы, php, циклы

Есть код, в котором выбирается максимальный элемент массива:

```
 $a1 = 1;
 $a2 = 2;
 $a3 = 3;
 $Mass1[1] = array($a1, $a2, $a3);
 echo "Max Element Of Array Is: ".max($Mass1[1]);
```

Надо отправить данные из цикла `for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++){}` в массив `$Mass1[1]`.

Я сам не додумался, как это сделать, прошу помощи!

Comment: Чтобы в массив поступили данные из цикла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Mass1[1][] = $i;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a1 = 1;
$a2 = 2;
$a3 = 3;

$mass = array();
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){
    $mass[$i] = ${'a'.$i};
}
```